# ¿Como utilizar una sola función en varias bases de datos? JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, poo

pues mi pregunta es simple, tengo las siguientes conexiones en una clase llamada Db:

```
 public static Connection connect2(){
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.32.1.199:3306/portalcomedor";
String user = "root";
String pass = "4dm1n.p05";
System.out.println("Conectando...");
try{
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass);

}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es posible conectar con el servidor\n"
    +"por favor intentelo mas tarde  " + e);
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

return connection;
}

public static Connection connect3(){
String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.32.1.199:3306/portal_dunotv";//Ubicación de la base
String user = "root";//nombre de usuario para acceder a la base
String pass = "4dm1n.p05";//password de la base
System.out.println("Conectando...");
try{
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,pass); //Conexión que contiene nuestra
     //URL, USUARIO Y CONTRASEÑA la almacenamos en connection.



}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No es posible conectar con el servidor\n"
    +"por favor intentelo mas tarde  " + e);
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
return connection; //Retornamos la conexión para usarla en otras clases.
}
```

Y tengo la siguiente función:

```
 public void busquedacontrol(JComboBox centrobox, String SSQL,String recibir) throws SQLException{
    try{
     Connection con = Db.connect3();
     PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(SSQL);
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){
    centrobox.addItem(rs.getInt(recibir));
    }
    }catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ah ocurrido un error al intentar llenar el combobox:\n " + e);
    } db.cerrarConexion();        
 }
```

Como es evidente, cuando utilizo la función llamo a la conexión:

```
   Connection con = Db.connect3();
```

Por lo que esa función solo funciona con esa base de datos, lo que quiero es usar esa misma función en diferentes bases de datos.
Agradecería mucho sus respuestas!

Comment: Puedes pasar el objecto `Connection` directamente por parámetro. De hecho, si hablamos de código limpio, a la función sólo le deberías pasar por parámetro la colección de `int` a renderizar en el `JComboBox`...

Comment: Ya lo he intentado, pero simplemente no logro conseguirlo.
Gracias por responder!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y por qué no te funcionó?

Comment: ¿Por qué repites tres veces el método `connect`? Simplemente usa un método y le pasas como parámetro la cadena de conexión, así reutilizas código.

Comment: VRoxa olvida lo que dije hace rato, ya me funciono, muchas gracias!

Comment: MrDave1999 Como hago eso?
Disculpa, soy muy novato en esto

Comment: @alexvargas6 Que no necesitas definir varios métodos para establecer la conexión. Podrías usar este prototipo: `public static Connection connect(String url)`. Luego cuando quieras invocar el método le pasas la URL que tu quieras. De este modo ahorras código y se ve mucho más legible.